# JS library to fast implement a slideshow

Tags: library, javascript, slideshow

I'm looking for a Javascript library that allow me to very easily create pictures slideshow on a website.

That I want to say as "fast" or "easy" to use library, is I want to pass to the lib an array of image's url, and when I turn on the lib (manually or automatically, it doesn't matter), a  good viewable slideshow should be visible on my website.

Then it can be some configuration options available, but I need that the first slideshow comes fast, without having to edit my DOM, or making lot of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would [Impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored) useful. It has everything you need

1 - JS Library to easily create presentations from code
2 - Configuration options avialable for transitions (including CSS3 effects)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like at the top of the iTunes store or Amazon? The big featured images that scroll to the left? If so, I would recommend [swipe.js](https://github.com/thebird/Swipe), even though the demo on their main site isn't currently working (Google around for another one). It's a very small, clean library with an option to auto-advance the swiper, thus making it a slideshow. It doesn't technically get images from an array, but the markup required is very minimal.

Another option like swipe.js is [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/), which is much bigger and feature-filled, including auto-advance to make it a slideshow.

If that's not what you're looking for, ResponsiveSlides.js (Sorry, you'll have to search for it; I can't include more links with my low reputation) looks like a good option. Similar to the two above options, but no swiping. Depends on jQuery.

If you are looking to make a more typical Powerpoint-style slideshow that the user navigates, I would recommend deck.js.

Answer (score 0):

There are *dozens* that do this with somewhat different options.

- [jssor](http://www.jssor.com) - jQuery slideshow
- [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - another jQuery slideshow
- [AmazingSlider](http://amazingslider.com)
- [SlidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com)

And of course jQuery has a long list [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/).

Almost all of them have compatible syntax, so you can try a few. I've used slick and it works great.